# AntiForgeryToken doesn't validate across sub project of same solution

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax, model-view-controller

I am implementing CSRF in MVC application. I created custom attribute to validate token as my inputs are json encode and call by Ajax. It works fine in the same project but when any button or link call url across different project in same solution then it doesn't validate the token. E.g logoff is in main page and calling different project's controller in the same solution. It keep on throwing "The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match." I have machine key already set up in the web configs. Can you guys please help me figure it out this issue.

Thank you

logoff method - main.js file in main project

```
A.ajax({
                    url: config.authenticationUrl + '/Account/LogOff',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: serialisedExtent,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    headers: {
                        '__RequestVerificationToken': $('input[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val()
                    }
                })
```

Controller method in account controller in authentication project

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> LogOff([ModelBinder(typeof(JsonNetModelBinder))] Exten extent)
        {
            if (User != null &&
                User.Identity != null &&
                User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
}

public sealed class ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
            var cookie = httpContext.Request.Cookies[AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName];
            AntiForgery.Validate(cookie != null ? cookie.Value : null, httpContext.Request.Headers["__RequestVerificationToken"]);
        }
```

Error:

> The anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.]
>   [exception : System.Web.Mvc.HttpAntiForgeryException (0x80004005): The
>   anti-forgery cookie token and form field token do not match.    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.TokenValidator.ValidateTokens(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, IIdentity identity, AntiForgeryToken sessionToken,
>   AntiForgeryToken fieldToken)    at
>   System.Web.Helpers.AntiXsrf.AntiForgeryWorker.Validate(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, String cookieToken, String formToken)    at
>   ValidateHeaderAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext
>   filterContext) in     at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__0(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)] [method : ] [caller : ] [context :
>   ]

Answer (score 1):

Try configuring all applications in your solution to specify the same [ApplicationDiscriminator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionoptions.applicationdiscriminator?view=aspnetcore-2.2) value:

```
var dataProtectionBuilder = services.AddDataProtection(configure =>
{
    configure.ApplicationDiscriminator = "SharedAppName";
});
```

> An identifier that uniquely discriminates this application from all
> other applications on the machine. The discriminator value is
> implicitly included in all protected payloads generated by the data
> protection system to isolate multiple logical applications that all
> happen to be using the same key material.
>
> If two different applications need to share protected payloads, they
> should ensure that this property is set to the same value across both
> applications.

Comment: Hi Jan,Thanks for your reply. I am not sure where do I set that.

Comment: I think I probably (wrongly) assumed your code was using asp.net core. In asp.net core, you'd configure the data protection in the `ConfigureServices()` method. If your code uses an older version of asp.net, I don't know how to set up the shared data protection.

Comment: No problem. Thanks Jan

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem today. Ajax requests going between different .NET Framework IIS apps running on the same domain.

[This blog post](https://blogs.perficient.com/2014/02/06/asp-net-mvc-anti-forgery-token-demystified-part-2-inside/) gave me the solution to my problem: in `Application_Start` of Global.asax.cs on each app, setting `AntiForgeryConfig.CookieName` to the same fixed value.

Without this, each app used different cookies for saving validation tokens.