# How to make Antiforgery tokens work across ASP.NET Core versions 2.1 and 3.1?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, antiforgerytoken, data-protection

In my company we have a multitude of applications running in one domain.

Some of them are still running on ASP.NET Core 2.1 (targeting .NET Framework 4.8), while most of them are on ASP.NET Core 3.1.

We noticed that ASP.NET Core 3.1 applications can't use ASP.NET Core 2.1 API's when they have the `ValidateAntiForgeryToken` specified. (While it is possible the other way around.) We believe this is caused by an incompatible DataProtection package...

We set up DataProtection with a common application name and common keys on a network share:

```
services
    .AddDataProtection()
    .SetApplicationName("coolcompanyapps")
    .PersistKeysToFileSystem(di);
```

And antiforgery is always setup the same with default names as follows:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(opt =>
{
    opt.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
    opt.Cookie.Name = "XSRF-TOKEN";
    opt.Cookie.Path = "/";
});
```

In the Microsoft docs it is described that you need to **[reference the same Data Protection package version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1#setapplicationname-1)**
Regrettably I completely fail over and over again on this one...

It should be easy as the data protection package consists of only 5 packages according to the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/introduction?view=aspnetcore-2.1#package-layout) :

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Abstractions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Extensions
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cryptography.KeyDerivation

I looks as if these 5 packages that constitute the data protection stack are incompatible between version 2.1 and 3.1... Is it ?

Comment: Do you have any error?Maybe you can try to set `ApplicationDiscriminator ` like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57848339/antiforgerytoken-doesnt-validate-across-sub-project-of-same-solution).

Comment: Good suggestion, but no solution. I'm already using SetApplicationName() which corresponds to setting the DataProtectionOptions.ApplicationDiscriminator.